# When click cell in Gridview then change selected index in DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have gridview with 10 columns and
I have dropdownlist list with numbers in items from 1 to 10.
When I click cell in gridview I want to get index of column (not row) and
that index should be selected index of dropdownlist.

Comment: use grid.HeaderRow.Cells in loop. It will give you column index

Comment: Can You write some code please?

Answer (score 0):

```
       //Get Cell Index
       int cellindex = GridView.SelectedRow.DataItemIndex;

       //Get HeaderText of that cell 
       string headerRowText = GridView.HeaderRow.Cells[cellindex].Text;

       //Loopthrough, find that header text, get column # of that col.
       foreach (DataControlField col in GridView.Columns)
       {
           if (col.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() == headerRowText .ToLower().Trim())
           {
               return GridView.Columns.IndexOf(col);
           }
       }
```

Comment: //Get Cell Index
int cellindex = GridView.SelectedRow.DataItemIndex;         This is row index not cell index